# s3-select querying data on field name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

I am trying to query data from json data in s3-select.

```
   {
    person = [
    {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Anshu",
            "Address": "Templestowe",
            "Car": "Jeep"
    }
    {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Ben Mostafa",
            "Address": "Las Vegas",
            "Car": "Mustang"
    }
    {
                    "Id": 3,
                    "Name": "Rohan Wood",
                    "Address": "Wooddon",
                    "Car": "VW"
    }
]
}

QUERY = "select * from S3Object s"
QUERY = "select s.person from S3Object s"
QUERY = "select s.person[0] from S3Object s"
QUERY = "select s.person[0].Name from S3Object s"
```

All these queries work fine and returns the respective object as desired but
when i am trying to search data on name/Car, it doesn't work.

```
QUERY = "select * from S3Object s where s.person.Name = \"Anshu\" "
```

error: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The column index at line 1, column 32 is invalid.

There is not much related content available on s3-select online.
Wondering whether we can query on field name or not!
There are no examples of select query with where clause for s3-select given in the documentation

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html seems to indicate that what you are doing should work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can't find this in any of AWS documentations, but I was just playing around and discovered a working syntax:

```
QUERY = "select * from S3Object s where 'Anshu' in s.person[*].Name"
```

Based on some deductions:

1. I know that syntax like WHERE ('blah' in s.tags) work when tags property is an array of string.
2. AWS documentation also say that s.person[#] should work when # is a valid index/digit.  Based on this, I discovered that using star (*) between square bracket, as in s.person[*].Name, also work.  This is after failed testing of various syntax like s.Person[], s.Person[#], s.Person[?], etc...

Proof with Python and Boto3:

```
import boto3

S3_BUCKET = 'your-bucket-name'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

r = s3.select_object_content(
        Bucket=S3_BUCKET,
        Key='your-file-name.json',
        ExpressionType='SQL',
        Expression="select * from s3object s where 'Anshu' in s.person[*].Name",
        InputSerialization={'JSON': {"Type": "Lines"}},
        OutputSerialization={'JSON': {}}
)

for event in r['Payload']:
    if 'Records' in event:
        records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
        print(records)
```

Weird, I know.  Remember to set [default] credentials in ~/.aws/credentials file.

Comment: FYI, looks like the AWS documentation was recently updated identifying star ( * ) ( * ) as a wildcard character and that's why the syntax above works.  Now you can use the syntax without worrying that Amazon might take it away because it's some kind of a fluke.

Comment: Saved my day!! For those using **SageMaker** I filtered images by tags running `SELECT * FROM S3Object s WHERE 1 IN s."test-machine-learning-image-tagging".annotations[*].class_id`. Where `test-machine-learning-image-tagging` is my first level manifest key.

Answer (score 5):

After reading the AWS doc, I find following SQL works fine.

```
select * from S3Object[*].person[*] as p where p.Name='Anshu'
```

This SQL will give you all the person whose name is 'Anshu', like:

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Anshu",
    "Address": "Templestowe",
    "Car": "Jeep"
}
```

When you see `[*]`, it means a json array.

Amazon S3 Select always treats a JSON document as an array of root-level values, so we use `S3Object[*]` in the SQL. And `person` value is a array, so we use `person[*]` in the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way. You need to "flatten" your JSON somewhat so it looks like this:

```
{
person: {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Anshu",
        "Address": "Templestowe",
        "Car": "Jeep"
    }
}
{ 
person: {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Ben Mostafa",
        "Address": "Las Vegas",
        "Car": "Mustang"
    }
}
{   
person:{
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "Rohan Wood",
        "Address": "Wooddon",
        "Car": "VW"
    }
}
```

The query below will work as expcted then

`select * from s3object s where s.person.name= 'Anshu'`

Comment: For your example file format to work, I find the syntax need to be (s.person["Name"] = 'Anshu')