# using s3 select I need to query JSON file. need some examples code snippets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-s3-select

using s3 select I need to query JSON file. need some examples code snippets using boto3

Thanks in advance
sundar

Comment: Did you try doing a web search? [Querying data without servers or databases using Amazon S3 Select | AWS Storage Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/querying-data-without-servers-or-databases-using-amazon-s3-select/)

Comment: I tried,  I couldn't find it for JSON.

Comment: How about: [s3-select querying data on field name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50979493/174777) and [Extract element from JSON file in S3 bucket using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641277/174777)? If found them via a search for: `boto3 "s3 select" json`

Comment: thanks, i'm understating it.